# jQuery - Adding a seconds printing to a timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have a jQuery code that press a button after  2 minutes.
I need it to print the seconds and minutes that left untill the event (for example - "X seconds left..").

here is the code:

```
function simulateClick(){
    $('#save').click();
};
setTimeout(simulateClick, 120000);
```

thanxs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function simulateClick(){
    $('#save').click();
};
var timeLeft = 120;
setTimeout(simulateClick, timeLeft * 1000);
setInterval(function(){
    timeLeft--;
    $("#timeleft").html(timeLeft + " seconds left");
}, 1000);
```

Add `<span id='timeleft'></span>` where you want to show seconds left.

Comment: Careful using setInterval for accurate timing: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/

Comment: A rough seconds left is okay for something where time is not mission critical.